# Jasper Reports - How to position the elements of a list

Tags: jasper-reports

I am making a report where I have a list with many items for the items. I have the following problems:

1. The list starts on a new page
2. Each item in the list starts on a new page.

I try to do is that the objects start immediately after the previous component. Let the elements separate and stack.

I have tried modifying the properties "stretch type" and "position type" but I can not get what I need.

[image: Screenshot of issue and what I would like]

[A link to a sample report](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhHHyeEGPtI5_BMcudfQf6MwAkDK)

Comment: Can you provide us minimal JRXML which produces the first problem you mentioned?

Comment: Of course. The file I added *"report1.jrxml"* is a simple sample of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set band property. Set split type to prevent.

[image: JasperSoft]